# How do I realize the Observer pattern in conjunction with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, observer-pattern

I've got a class which manages a config file `SettingsController`, it allows a `SettingsClient` (one pure virtual function, no members) to be registered. A `SettingsClient` will be notified when a relevant configuration entry changes so it can refresh.

Now I have a `RepositoryBase` which needs some configuration entries and thus inherits `SettingsClient` and registers at the `SettingsController` and a concrete repository `ConcreteRepository` which also needs some configuration entries and inherits the client and registers at the controller.

`ConcreteRepository` inherits `RepositoryBase` and both inherit `SettingsClient` to be able to register at the controller (in Java the `ConcreteRepository` would `extend` the `RepositoryBase` and both would `implement` the `SettingsClient`).

My problem is: The compiler warns me not to do this as it is ambiguous. Sadly virtual inheritance won't help me here as it would overwrite the implemented function of either `ConcreteRepository` or `RepositoryBase` and so disable the refresh function of one of the two classes.

Is there some way to realize this inheritance-observer-combination? I am thinking this might be a design flaw and `RepositoryBase` needs to be a member of `ConcreteRepository`(?)

Here is some code to give an overview:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

class SettingsClient {
public:
  virtual void reloadSettings() = 0;
};

class SettingsController {
  void notify(){
    for(SettingsClient* client : clients){
      client->reloadSettings(); // error! reloadSettings() of RepositoryBase or ConcreteRepository?
    }
  }
  void registerClient(SettingsClient *client) {
    clients.push_back(client);
  }

  std::vector<SettingsClient*> clients;
};

class RepositoryBase : private SettingsClient {
  // ...
  virtual void reloadSettings() {
    std::cout << "Reloading Base!" << "\n";
  }
  // ...
};

class ConcreteRepository : private SettingsClient, private RepositoryBase {
  // ...
  virtual void reloadSettings() {
    std::cout << "Reloading ConcreteRepository!" << "\n";
  }
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Public inheritance so the polymorphism with work, SettingsClient needs a virtual destructor, ConcreteRepository does not need to also inherit SettingsClient because it already is one via RepositoryBase, and explicitly call RepositoryBase's reloadSettings from ConcreteBase's if you need to. There is no mechanism in C++ that will default to calling multiple base classes overridden members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for `ConcreteRepository` to also inherit from `SettingsClient`. Your can register your repository once in the base class constructor, and then call the base class `reloadSettings` from the subclass version.

```
class RepositoryBase : private SettingsClient
{
public:
  RepositoryBase(SettingsController& controller)
  {
    controller.registerClient(this);
  }

private:
  void reloadSettings() override
  {
    std::cout << "Reloading RepositoryBase\n";
  }
};

class ConcreteRepository : public RepositoryBase
{
public:
  using RepositoryBase::RepositoryBase;

private:
  void reloadSettings() override
  {
    std::cout << "Reloading ConcreteRepository\n";
  }
};
```

We use *private* inheritance from `SettingsClient` to prevent `reloadSettings` from being publicly visible in subclasses. If we need to call the base class function, we can use *protected* inheritance instead, at the cost of weakened encapsulation.

```
class RepositoryBase : protected SettingsClient
{
public:
  RepositoryBase(SettingsController& controller)
  {
    controller.registerClient(this);
  }

protected:
  void reloadSettings() override
  {
    std::cout << "Reloading RepositoryBase\n";
  }
};

class ConcreteRepository : public RepositoryBase
{
public:
  using RepositoryBase::RepositoryBase;

protected:
  void reloadSettings() override
  {
    RepositoryBase::reloadSettings();
    std::cout << "Reloading ConcreteRepository\n";
  }
};
```

If you need or prefer to register two separate clients for the base class and subclass, you can use composition.

```
class RepositoryBase
{
public:
  RepositoryBase(SettingsController& controller)
  {
    controller.registerClient(&client);
  }

private:
  struct : public SettingsClient
  {
    void reloadSettings() override
    {
      std::cout << "Reloading RepositoryBase\n";
    }
  } client;
};

class ConcreteRepository : public RepositoryBase
{
public:
  ConcreteRepository(SettingsController& controller) : RepositoryBase(controller)
  {
    controller.registerClient(&client);
  }

private:
  struct : public SettingsClient
  {
    void reloadSettings() override
    {
      std::cout << "Reloading ConcreteRepository\n";
    }
  } client;
};
```

You can give the client a pointer to its repository if you need to access its non-static members.